# android openid authentication

Tags: android, authentication, openid

It might sound silly but i went through a lot of code examples for Open ID authentication of android application. This one says 
      https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode
that you have to make a webview and from webbrowser get the token and all but what i want is really simple , given options for google, facebook and twitter, I want user to select one and authenticate without any browser or so. Is that possible?

This one also i tried but it apparently seems to support only google accounts but i want all three

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenID technology is based on browser confirmation, so you can't identify the end-user without it. Take a look at this link: http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-code/2011-January/000190.html

Comment: how about aquery library, it seems to have handels to authenticate http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/Authentication  has anyone used it before. I am actually tired of using different codes none of which seems to work for me.

Comment: As I can understand from description, it's OAuth library - not OpenID. See the difference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_vs._pseudo-authentication_using_OAuth

Comment: so is that mandatory that if i want open it login i need to setup an html page and from there do the open-id authentication, many open source would be available for that or there is any simpler option available. Thanx in advance :)